# How Do I Access Elements in the Shadow DOM using Selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Sorry for not providing the details, let me provide a detailed info.

Scenario: Intend to click 3-dot option menu, then from the popup sub-menu, select "Export" and select "CSV" in subsequent pop-up sub-menu.

Problem Statement: Noticed the 3-dot is within shadow-root (open). the html skeleton looks like:

```
<html>
 <head>...</head>
  <body>
   <macroponent-abcdefg>
    #shadow-root (open)
     #shadow-root (open)
      #shadow-root (open)
       <iframe>
        #document
         <html>
          <body>
           <div>
            <div>
             <span>
              <div>
               <div>
                <div>
                 <table>
                  <thread>
                   <tr>
                    <th>
                     <span>
                      <i>the element I want to grab</i>
                     </span>
                    </th>
                   </tr>
                  </thread>
                 </table>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
             </span>
            </div>
           </div>
          </body>
         </html>
        </iframe>
       </macroponent-abcdefg>
      </body>
     </html>
```

How can I access the component `i` within the 3-layer shadow-root?

Besides, I tried to use SelectorsHub Chrome extension and found the following results for the component `i`:

```
Rel cssSelector: i[aria-label='Number column options']
Rel XPath: //i[@aria-label='Number column options']jQuery: $("i[aria-label='Number column options']")
normal copy element: <i class="icon-ellipsis-vertical col-menu list_header_context list-column-icon" aria-haspopup="true" data-type="list2_hdricon" role="button" tabindex="0" title="" aria-label="Number column options" data-original-title="Column options" aria-expanded="true" xpath="1" style=""></i>
```

However, when I tried to find element by CSS_Selector, python output returned `no such element found`

Here is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome().maximize_window()
driver.get('https://micron.service-now.com')

one = driver.find_element(By. CSS_SELECTOR, "i[aria-label='Number column options']")
 
actions = ActionChains(one)
actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
driver.quit()
```

Let me know if y'all need further information.

Comment: `Elements in the Shadow DOM` _where it is ?_

Comment: @Akzy, I just updated my question, you may have a look. Appreciate it.

Comment: can you share url of the page?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the information you need to use the javascript command `querySelector(css_selector).shadowRoot` and then `driver.switch_to.frame` since the inner `shadow-roor` contains a `iframe` element.

```
iframe = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('macroponent-abcdefg').shadowRoot.shadowRoot.shadowRoot.querySelector('iframe')"]

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

i = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'i')
print(i.text) # should print "the element I want to grab"
```